# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType" on path: DexPathList

Tags: java, android, ory

I just integrated an SDK ([Ory Java client](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/sh.ory/ory-client/1.1.33)) into my Android app, but when actually making a request using that SDK, I get this runtime error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/ws/rs/core/GenericType;
    at sh.ory.model.UiNodeAttributes.validateJsonObject(UiNodeAttributes.java:380)
[..]   
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType" on path: DexPathList[[<paths removed for better readability>]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
[..]
```

How can I fix that? Could I somehow add the library containing `javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType`? Is that possible at all as it seems to be part of the Oracle JDK?

Comment: "How can I fix that?" -- probably not easily. That library is designed to be used with the JDK, for desktop or server Java. Is there an Android library that you could use instead?

Comment: thanks, that's what I already expected ): There is no Android library version, but the YAML from which the client was generated using openapi generator is available. That's the way I want to try, I have a question posted for that at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76327679/generate-api-client-from-yaml-for-android

Comment: Robert, wer did you see, that it's set to compile scope only? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry stefan please forget what I had wrote, this was nonsense. The only part that was true is that the mentioned missing class is present in that library and as it is a dependency it should be included into the app. Not sure why it is missing. Just for curiosity have you checked the APK file e.g. using Jadx if the class `javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType` is really missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the SDK ([Ory Java Client](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/sh.ory/ory-client/)) by generating it myself using openapi-generator version **7.0.1**.

Steps:

- Clone the [SDK GitHub repo](https://github.com/ory/sdk/tree/master)
- Change generator in file [generate.sh](https://github.com/ory/sdk/blob/master/scripts/generate.sh#L70) to version **7.0.1**

```
    -  openapi-generator-cli version-manager set 6.2.1
    +  openapi-generator-cli version-manager set 7.0.1
```

- Build client following the steps in [README.md](https://github.com/ory/sdk/blob/master/README.md#debugging-failing-tests-on-ci)

Comment: did you also try to use it? Building it was not the issue, but using it (on Android)

Comment: Yes I'm also able to use it. I copied the generated sources to my project and added the gradle dependencies. You can take a look to my github repository [Ory Auth capacitor plugin], (https://github.com/frnd/capacitor-ory-auth/tree/main/android) were I'm currently testing it.