# What's the difference between the Kotlin and Android generators provided by OpenAPI Generator?

Tags: android, kotlin, openapi-generator

Given an OpenAPI definition file ([this one](https://github.com/ory/sdk/blob/master/clients/client/java/api/openapi.yaml)) I want to generate a client that works with Android. OpenAPI Generator offers Kotlin as well as Android as "targets". What's the difference between them? Which one should I use? Are they both "up to date"?

Comment: If nothing else, they vary in the HTTP library that they use. I'd try the kotlin one with `jvm-okhttp4`, as that advertises support for Android and isn't using Volley.

Comment: "and isn't using Volley" - sounds like Volley isn't good? Wouldn't that be perfect as it's designed for Android?

Comment: Volley was discontinued some time ago.

Comment: interesting. do you have a source? Cause I could not find this information via google search.

Comment: https://github.com/google/volley has not had any commits in about two years, roughly coinciding with their last published artifact. The documentation has been yanked out of developer.android.com and resides in [an independent Web site](https://google.github.io/volley/) (part of their GitHub repo). "Discontinued" might have been too strong of a term for me to use, but it's close. OkHttp won the Android HTTP stack war, and it wasn't close.